# Xcode Storyboard graph paper

Tags: ios, xcode

Where can I find the Xcode Storyboard graph paper png's?

The graph paper has about three different sections, that change depending on the zoom level. I would like to look at the images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pull the graph images out of the Xcode.app's bundle. Just go into where ever Xcode.app is installed (probably /Applications or /Developer) and right click on the icon and select "open package contents". The image will be somewhere in the directory, but may require some manual searching.

Remember though, the images are owned and copyrighted by Apple, so you can't re-purpose them (unless you're using them for personal use).